# SQL Predicate vs Mutable Array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database, core-data, nsmutablearray

I currently have a database of 'school' entities and 'name' entities.  [School <---- (one to many) -------->>name]. I am displaying the database in a table and want the user to be able to search by typing.  The table will be updated every time the search bar text changes so I need this to be efficient.

Right now I fetch a Mutable array of all the school entities in the data base then filter the array based on the text they entered.  Would it be more considerably more efficient to use an NSPredicate to fetch only the relevant schools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"schoolTitle CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchTitle];
```

schoolTitle is the attribute of the entity.

Answer (score 1):

Efficient is a loaded word; Your current approach is likely the best performing, but uses more RAM.  Like jeremy said, predicates will be slower when accessing the flash memory data store.  If you can assert that the memory usage is reasonable (measure), your current approach will probably be a better user experience.  Keep in mind the lowest common denominator of devices your application may run on (ex. iPhone 3g).

Comment: ok so if i say had a 1000 entities each with a relationship with maybe 2 or 3 names how much ram could an array of that size possibly take up?

Comment: The easiest way to analyze memory usage is with Instruments, which comes with Developer Tools alongside xcode.  Click-hold on your 'Run' button and select 'Profile', and select Allocations from the memory section.  Apple's guide to Instruments is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

No.  Under the hood it is doing much the same thing, except possibly calling out to disk more often i.e. each time you run the predicate.

Having said that, there may special circumstances in your case that make my statement wrong.  Try implementing it both ways and gather some performance stats.